# reusing data read from XML file

Tags: java, android

I am reading data from an XML file, and I want to store that data in variables so I can easily reuse that data throughout my application.

Is there a proper way to do this in Android/Java?

Thanks

Comment: I'd say parse your XML and assign the data to a Properties file, that way you can use it across your application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on the scenario. The simple answer is populate an object.

```
 class YourXmlAsAnObject {

  int someIntField;
  String someStringField;

 }
```

Then if you want to pass this between Activity's you can serialise it.

Comment: do you mean read the data from the XML file, and then serialise that data to another file?

Comment: Yeah read the data with a Sax parser, put it into this object ( a domian object) then use that within your app.

Comment: Im sorry, but I'm confused. So I would parse the XML with Sax, and then write to another file.  But then I'd have to write another method to parse that new file.

Comment: No. Files have nothing to do with it. You would use a sax parser to read the XML and translate it into a class that you can use in your application. Find any tutorial on the net: http://www.technotalkative.com/android-sax-parsing-example/

Answer (score 1):

Use static variable in the main class

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of [LINK](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) for storing your data. And it is also recommended by the google also.

Comment: this sounds interesting...I've never used LINK before, is this widely used in the Android dev community?

Comment: Yes because it is the basic data storage types that can be used throughout the application.

Answer (score 1):

use dom parser it will fetch all data first.

Answer (score 1):

Map your XML in a custom Java model using SAX.

You can see an example [here](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Android_XML_SAX_Parser_Example).